# Copyright: Use an Audio Clip of a DVD

Tags: copyright, internet

I have a question regarding copyright-laws.

I want to write an **Android App**. In this app I want to use an Audio-Clip of a Simpsons-DVD, that I bought. This audio-clip is about 20 seconds long.

This particular section that I want to use can be found on Youtube many times, but instead of just using it, I want to ask you. The app should be for free and I don't want to include advertisements.

Am I allowed to use a short clip? If not, who do I have to ask, to get the permission? Who is the actual owner of these things?

Comment: If you watch the credits or visit their site there will be someone or a team named to contact.

Comment: What do you want to use it for?  Your intended use *could* constitute "fair use" and not require license/permission of the copyright holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the clip without explicit permission from the copyright holder would be a copyright violation. Other people also violating the copyright is no reason that you can do the same and does not mean that the copyright holder will not go after you. Not making any money is not an excuse to violate copyright, but in some jurisdictions there are "fair use" exceptions which might apply to you under some conditions.

The Simpsons copyright is by 20th Century Fox, but they sub-licensed the exclusive rights to local companies in many jurisdictions.